# Grails render view within another view. Contextpath to views folder

Tags: grails-2.0

Trying to render a view from another view in Grails.

```
<g:render contextPath="??" template="first_view" />
```

I am at index.gsp and willing to render a view found under a specific controller (ex: user/first_view.gsp). I understand that the correct path of the view should be set in the "contextPath" as stated in the docs: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/render.html

What is the contextPath to views of the app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you should have to set the context path at all. From the render docs:

> Note that if the value of the template attribute starts with a '/' it will be resolved relative to the views directory. This is useful for sharing templates between views. Without the leading '/' it will be first be resolved relative to the current controller's view directory then, failing that, the top level views directory.

In your case (`<g:render contextPath="??" template="first_view" />`), the render tag will look in the directory of your current view for _first_view.gsp. If you want it to locate the template in the user view directory, change the tag to `<g:render template="/user/first_view" />`

Notice the path in the template attribute must start with '/'

Comment: I tested this already, but I was missing the fact that Grails wants the second view to have an underscore in front of it.
This is also documented at: http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Tags/render.html in the description section 
Thx Bob McCracken